# Access data export to excel: 1 issue- count

Tags: excel, ms-access, export, vba

I have a button in access that runs queries and dumps the info into an Access table, then that table is used to populate an excel sheet.  This excel sheet is then linked to a 2nd worksheet (B) that has the formatting needed to submit for state reporting.  I am having an issue that I need to fix with my process.

1. I have a record count- currently on the top of the formatted worksheet, but it has to be at the bottom of my formatted worksheet- it needs to be in the A column on the row after the last entry.   How do I do this as since there's no set row to show record count? 1 report it may be 5, next report may be 35 rows.

I do the record count from the original (un-formatted) excel sheet that has the data dumped from Access, so it's accurate.  I just need help moving it! end

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't ask double-barrelled questions. Ask only a single question, and provide sufficient details for us to be able to fully answer it. This is not a question and ideas or question and pointers site, it's a questions and answers site. You can read more by following the [tour], reading [ask] and provide an [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. I stripped out the one question and just need help with moving record count